# Not getting simulated output for an error free verilog code

Tags: verilog

I'm somewhat new to verilog. So this question might be very simple. 
I'm trying to simulate an finite state machine using verilog.
Brief description: 
There are three states: 0,1 & 2. By default, State is 0.
The state changes to 1 only if input is 01.
The state changes to 2 only if input is 10.
The state changes back to 0 only if input is 00.
The code is getting simulated successfully, but I.m getting no output. Please help me with the problem.

Code: (State.v)

```
module State(
    input clk,
    input reset,
     input [3:0] in,
     output [3:0] out,
     output [3:0] state
    );

     wire clk,reset;
     wire [3:0] in;
     reg [3:0] out;
     reg [3:0] state;

     always @(posedge clk or posedge reset)
      begin
      if (reset == 1)
        begin
            state = 0;
        end
      else 
        begin
            case (state)
                0: if(in == 2'b01)
                         state = 1;
                        else
                         state = 0;
                1: if(in == 2'b10) 
                        state = 2;
                      else
                       state = 1;
                2: if(in == 2'b00)
                        state = 0;
                      else
                       state = 2;
                default: state = 0;     
            endcase 
        end 
     end    

     always @(*)
        begin
            case (state)
                0: out = 2'b00;
                1: out = 2'b01;
                2: out = 2'b10;
                default: out = 2'b00;
            endcase     
        end     

endmodule
```

Testbench: (StateTestBench.v)

```
module StateTestBench;

    // Inputs
    reg clk;
    reg reset;
    reg [3:0] in;

    // Outputs
    reg [3:0] out;
    reg [3:0] state;

    always
        begin
            #1 clk = !clk;
        end 

    // Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
    State uut (
        .clk(clk), 
        .reset(reset), 
        .in(in),
        .out(out),
        .state(state) 
    );

    initial begin
        // Initialize Inputs
        clk = 0;
        reset = 0;

        #1 reset = 1;
        #10 reset = 0;
        #5 in = 2'b00;
        #10 in = 2'b01;
        #10 in = 2'b10;



    end

endmodule
```

Comment: There should be a compiler warnings because you are mixing ANSI and non-ANSI header styles. With ANSI style you should not re-declare nets and variables with the same names as port. Change `output [3:0]` to `output reg [3:0]` and remove remove the `wire` and `reg` declarations in `State` to be compliant with ANSI header styles. `state` should also be assigned with non-blocking assignments (`<=`), not blocking assignments (`=`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you simulate state.v instead of StateTestBench.v. Because your testbench has a bug! Outputs out and state MUST be wires.